# how to reload styles after javascript call?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have the following html:

```
<div class="sk-toolbar-tools-primary">
   <span class="sk-custom-select">
      <select name="music-sort-select" id="music-sort-select">
          <option value="option1">Company 1</option>
          <option value="option2">Company 2</option>
          <option value="option3">Company 3</option>
     </select>
  </span>
</div>
```

As you can see this select element is styled using CSS style, Now if I publish companies from database using AJAX call and injecting the response to the select using this Javascript function:

```
 function loadCompanies(){
    var companies= getCompanies();
    var select = document.getElementById("music-sort-select");
    for(var i = 0; i<companies.length; i++) {
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(companies[i].name,companies[i].id);
    }

}
```

where `getCompanies()` is doing the AJAX call, what happens is that the Javascript function works fine and i can see the data from DB published using the developer tools in chrome, But the select stops working and it does not open and show options. I guess that's because the new options are not taking the CSS style when they are loaded after the page has already loaded.
How can I sort this out?

Comment: The jQuery on() function may help here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: how would `on` fix help?  I'm calling the JS function on page load.

Comment: What type of Ajax do you use, asyncronous or syncronous?

Comment: @Engineer I am using synchronous at the moment .. as asynchronous does not work at chrome when I am testing locally for some reason..but Ajax call works fine and the result is returned normally.

Answer (score 0):

CSS should be applied instantly by the browser, even if new things are added to the DOM. Are you using a select-box replacement script to make the select box stylable via CSS?

Comment: Can you post a link so we can actually see what's happening? CSS won't stop a select box from opening, and adding new items dynamically to a select box also shouldn't stop it from working. Are you browser testing at all? Select boxes are notoriously difficult to style cross-browser, hence the proliferation of select box replacement scripts and plugins...

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using Jquery
Give your styles,button ids

```
jQuery(function($) {
var $output = $('#output')
  , $style = $('#styles')
  , $button = $('#preview')
;
$ed.val($style.html());
$button.click(function() {
    $style.html($output.val());
    return false;
});
});
```